# Homepage in Django isn't working

Tags: python, html, django

I'm currently trying to create a homepage for Django, but when I test it, it just shows me a blank page with nothing on it. This is what I have so far. First is my URL page from mysite:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'',include('firstapp.urls')),
]
```

and my url page from firstapp:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from firstapp.views import HomePage

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

this is my views page:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    def home(request):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

this is the base.html which extends to home.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "css/base.css" %}'/>
    </head>
<html>
<p>{{ variable }}</p>
<script src= '{% static "js/base.js" %}'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally home.html itself.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">
<p>Testing Home</p>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Now if it works, I should be seeing "Testing Home"...but...I see nothing. I just get an empty white page. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: There's no block defined in your base template.

Comment: your `template_name` in your view is pointing to a subdirectory, make sure you have created the `home` directory in the template folder

Comment: Note, that `home()` method in your view is never called. You don't need it anyway; rendering the template is the default action of a TemplateView. You should remove that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `base.html` doesn't have a `{% block body %}` defined anywhere in it. You need blocks to be defined in the template you're extending, otherwise you'll have nothing to override inside the extended template.

**base.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>{{ variable }}</p>

    {% block body %}{% endblock %}

    <script src= '{% static "js/base.js" %}'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** I also fixed your opening `<body>` tag which you incorrectly had as `<html>`, leaving you with two `<html>` opening tags in your template.